# How do I set an image size to fit and look the same in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image fix itself to the size of an area but when I use `size: 25%;` it is invalid.

```
<style>
.imageContent {
height: auto;
min-height: 300px;
background-color: #fff;
width: 100%;
}
.imageContent img {
size: 25%;
grid-column: 2;
}
</style>
<div class="imageContent">
<img src="computerIMGedit.jpg" />
</div>
```

and then nothing happens, the image stays the same size and nothin at all changes! I am using sublime and according to sublime, the '%' is invalid in that context because when something is valid then it will change the text color to a light blue etc. But nothing happens with the '%'

Comment: Where did you read about this `size` attribute? Why aren't you using `width` and `height`?

Comment: size is an attribute to HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size CSS at-rule descriptor, used with the @page at-rule, defines the size and orientation of the box which is used to represent a page.

As i can see that you are not using @page rule, and using image, you should use width property :-

```
.imageContent img {
  width : 25%;
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, it will fit in for all sizes:

> Use `display: block;` to fit into the div.

```css
.imageContent {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.imageContent img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<style>

</style>
<div class="imageContent">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" />
</div>
```